# How to display id with name in url in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to display id with name in my url, Currently, my url is like 
http://localhost/classified/1

but i want it to print like
http://localhost/classified/1/Health-and-Beauty

here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category-classifieds.php?sub_id=$1 [L]
```

here is my php

```
<?php 
$categories_name = $_GET['categories_name'];
$result = "SELECT * FROM sub_categories where categories_name='$categories_name'";
$data =mysqli_query ($conn, $result);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{ 
$sub_categories_name = $row['sub_categories_name'];
$sub_id = $row['sub_id'];

<a href="<?php print $sub_id;); ?>">
    <div class="cat-box p-0 m-0 cat-url">
        <p class="subcat-url"><?php echo $sub_categories_name;?></p>
    </div>
</a>
<?php }?>
```

I have tried this

```
<a href="<?php print $sub_id . '/' . str_replace(' ', '-', $sub_categories_name); ?>">
```

and i get the required url i.e. 
http://localhost/classified/1/Health-and-Beauty

but the page didn't display any data

Please help me out, i am poorly stucked in it

Comment: My 2 cents: 1. `$_GET['categories_name']` Why? You're using `sub_id` in your rewrite rule. 2. Do you actually have a category with a _name_ of `Health-and-Beauty` in your database? Try using/adding a slug. 3. In your rule you're only using one parameter (sub_id), which would make urls like `/classified/1/Physio` possible. I'm out

Answer (score 0):

**Changes in htaccess**

```
#Exrtact int and string from url and pass to file.
RewriteRule ^(\d+)(?!\w)\/(\w*)$ category-classifieds.php?sub_id=$1&subcategory_slug=$2 [L]
```

Comment: please share directory architecture. What are the file names and their use.

Comment: i am getting previous page select category in 'categories_name' and on this page i am showing its sub-categories and by clicking on it, it redirect me to selected sub-category url